# threaded for loop reaching values it's not supposed to reach

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm messing around with multithreading in c++ and here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

void read(int i);

bool isThreadEnabled;
std::thread threads[100];

int main()
{
    isThreadEnabled = true; // I change this to compare the threaded vs non threaded method
    if (isThreadEnabled)
    {
        for (int i = 0;i < 100;i++) //this for loop is what I'm confused about
        {
            threads[i] = std::thread(read,i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            threads[i].join();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            read(i);
        }
    }
}

void read(int i)
{
    int w = 0;
    while (true) // wasting cpu cycles to actually see the difference between the threaded and non threaded
    {
        ++w;
        if (w == 100000000) break;
    }
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

in the for loop that uses threads the console prints values in a random order ex(5,40,26...) which is expected and totally fine since threads don't run in the same order as they were initiated...

but what confuses me is that the values printed are sometimes more than the maximum value that `int i` can reach (which is 100), values like 8000,2032,274... are also printed to the console even though `i` will never reach that number, I don't understand why ?

Comment: Do you also get empty lines between numbers sometimes?

Comment: yes actually I didn't pay attention to it before, how could multiple i be glued together ? I'm still fairly new to multithreading

Comment: This might help you understand: `std::cout << "'" << i << "'" << std::endl;` - when you see numbers that are not surrounded by single quotes you will see that your prints can start to get interleaved so "22\n" "33\n" from different threads could be printed "2323\n\n" etc....

Comment: @code_fodder yes! you're right, I didn't know about this, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```cpp
std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

is actually equivalent to

```cpp
std::cout << i;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

And thus while thread safe (meaning there's no undefined behaviour), the order of execution is undefined. Given two threads the following execution is possible:

```
T20: std::cout << 20
T32: std::cout << 32
T20: std::cout << std::endl
T32: std::cout << std::endl
```

which results in `2032` in console (glued numbers) and an empty line.

The simplest (not necessarily the best) fix for that is to wrap this line with a [shared mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard):

```cpp
{
    std::lock_guard lg { mutex };
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

(the brackets for a separate scope are not needed if the `std::cout << i << std::endl;` is the last line in the function)